# Is there any way to get better deals when trading in Risen?

Tags: risen

Can't seem to find any barter like skills...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no possibility to enhance your trading skills. The trading-system in Risen is nearly the same as in Gothic 3 so you just have to find many items and sell them.

But don't worry , you will get rich in Risen after some time ;)